# PHP isset() returning false when should return true?

Tags: php, isset

Alright... so on my forms, I am setting all the fields to something like this:

`name="formdata['name']"` and `name="formdata['active']"`.

Of course, that means whatever is entered in those fields should be stored in `$_POST['formdata']['name']` and `$_POST['formdata']['active']`.

I do my values that way because I pass the 'formdata' to a couple of functions I have written (which work as they should.) Now let's say I'm using this to edit an item or add a new item -- the name will go through those functions as it should and the item will save with its name, but 'active' will never save as it should. The entry field is a checkbox -- if it's checked, the value is "1".

If I `print_r($_POST['formdata'])` after entering 'Name' and checking 'active', I get this: `Array ( ['name'] => Name ['active'] => 1 )`.

Looks fine, right? But when I do the following:

```
if (!isset($_POST['formdata']['active']) echo "Error 1";
if (empty($_POST['formdata']['active']) echo "Error 2";
if ($_POST['formdata']['active'] != 1) echo "Error 3";
```

They all return errors! I am baffled by this. Am I overlooking something very simple? I have thought about this for at least 2 hours now.

Comment: The first two aren't valid; they have mismatched parentheses. Is there a (good) reason you're putting everything in a parameter called `formdata`?

Comment: Tried to var_dump the variable to test if it is really set?

Comment: @minitech -- You are right, there are missing parenthesis. I just typed those lines into the question box here rather than copy/pasting -- I can assure you that the syntax for those is correct in my actual .php file. And yes, I have a good enough reason to put them into `formdata` -- I pass it off to functions that take the data from the form and automatically set the properties of an object, and build a 'return' so that if an error is found when the model validates the input and the user is taken back to the form, the fields that were entered will already be filled out.

Comment: @BloodyWorld -- `var_dump($_POST['formdata']['active']);` prints out NULL even though `print_r($_POST['formdata']);` shows `['active'] => 1`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Remove the single quotes from the input names** in your HTML so it reads:

```
name="formdata[active]"
```

Adding the single quotes would mean you would have to access the array in PHP as:

```
$_POST['formdata']['\'active\'']
```

or

```
$_POST['formdata']["'active'"]
```

which is highly inconvenient.

Comment: Thank you! I knew it had to be something stupidly obvious! :)

Answer (score 0):

missing parenthesis:

```
if (!isset($_POST['formdata']['active'])) echo "Error 1";
if (empty($_POST['formdata']['active'])) echo "Error 2";
```